# node js - I am having some trouble with JSON.parse()

Tags: node.js

I have been playing around with the youtube API and node.js, so far I have been able to get a response from the API and `console.log` it onto the terminal.

When I try to get the response and use `JSON.parse`, I get a weird error:

```
Got response: 200

undefined:1
http://www.w3.or
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_temp4/index.js:19:10)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1137:24)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:354:27)
```

This is my script:

```
var http = require("http");

var searchQuery = "cats";
var queryResponse;

var options = {
  host: 'gdata.youtube.com',
  path: "/feeds/api/videos?q=" + searchQuery + "&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json"
};

http.get(options, function(response) {
  console.log("Got response: " + response.statusCode);

  response.on('data', function(chunk){
    queryResponse += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function(){
    JSON.parse(queryResponse);
    console.log('end');
  });
}).end();
```

Comment: What's the value of queryResponse before you try to parse it?

Comment: it prints [this](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=cats&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json) on the terminal if i log it.

EDIT: a more readable version - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=cats&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The variable `queryResponse` is set to `undefined` and you are doing `queryResponse += chunk` in the 'data' envent handler which means `queryResponse = queryResponse + chunk` so you get

```
undefined{"youtube":["Api", "response"]}
```

you can fix it by instantiating `queryResponse` as an empty string `var queryResponse = ''`

Comment: It's a good convention to check the type of the data before passing it to parse too.

Comment: thanks mister, this was really simple to fix, you just need to pin point what's going on.